# faster XML generation using Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, builder

Am using Rails 2.3.5 for one of the mobile app's backend. It generates hell lot of XML. I have come across that the [fast_xs](http://rubygems.org/gems/fast_xs) gem speeds up the xml-generation by a lot. Now, my questions is - should I use this gem in Rails 2.3.5 or does Rails 2.3.5 already have this mechanism built in it.

Answer (score 0):

No version of Rails has the `fast_xs` gem built in. You can get it by either installing `fast_xs` or `hpricot`

Note: Builder version 3 breaks it (used by Rails 3.1) so you will need a monkey patch to work around (or wait for a new version of fast_xs)